# How to get the thread execution state?

Tags: c#, power-saving

On Windows, each thread has an execution state which can be set by calling [`SetThreadExecutionState`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-setthreadexecutionstate). For example, if a thread calls:

```
SetThreadExecutionState(ES_CONTINUOUS | ES_DISPLAY_REQUIRED)
```

then Windows will not turn off the display, until that thread changes its execution state, or terminates.

It can be accessed from C#:

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)] SetThreadExecutionState(...)
```

But, while `SetThreadExecutionState` sets the execution state, there doesn't appear to be any equivalent `GetThreadExecutionState` API. `kernel32.dll` exports `SetThreadExecutionState` but not `GetThreadExecutionState`. I tried:

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)] internal static extern uint GetThreadExecutionState();
```

But I got a `System.EntryPointNotFoundException` saying `GetThreadExecutionState` does not exist in `kernel32.dll`.

How then can I find out the execution state of the current thread without changing it?

Comment: ExecutionState of what? What Exception? Please read [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Exception:

    System.EntryPointNotFoundException

I want to readout out the Setting of 

    SetThreadExceutionState(...)
because I set it with a button. This button hat to be renamed.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @MoaByter Your question was not stated clearly. I think I understand what you were asking, so I rewrote it to be clearer.

Answer (score 2):

`SetThreadExecutionState` does two different things:

1. Change the current thread's execution state flags
2. Reset system-wide idle timers

It does (1) when you pass in `ES_CONTINUOUS`; otherwise it does (2).

So, if you don't pass `ES_CONTINUOUS` as input, it will not change the current thread's execution flags, it will only reset idle timers.

When resetting idle timers, `ES_SYSTEM_REQUIRED` tells it to reset the system idle timer, and `ES_DISPLAY_REQUIRED` tells it to reset the display idle timer. If you don't pass either of `ES_SYSTEM_REQUIRED` or `ES_DISPLAY_REQUIRED`, it won't reset any idle timers.

In other words, `SetThreadExecutionState(0)` is essentially a no-op – it doesn't change the thread's execution flags, nor does it reset any idle timers. But it does do something useful – it returns the current value of the thread execution flags.

So, the `GetThreadExecutionState` you were looking for doesn't exist, but you don't need it, because `SetThreadExecutionState(0)` is equivalent.

Note that the return value always includes `ES_CONTINUOUS`. So, if your thread doesn't have any execution state flags set, `SetThreadExecutionState(0) == ES_CONTINUOUS`. Whereas, suppose the current thread has `ES_SYSTEM_REQUIRED` set, then `SetThreadExecutionState(0) == ES_CONTINUOUS|ES_SYSTEM_REQUIRED`.

If the function fails, the return value doesn't include `ES_CONTINUOUS`, it will return `0`. As far as I am aware, the only way the function can fail, is if you pass some unsupported flag.

Note as well as the per-thread execution state flags, there are also system-wide flags. You can get those using [`CallNtPowerInformation`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/powerbase/nf-powerbase-callntpowerinformation) with `SystemExecutionState` information level. If any thread has `SetThreadExecutionState(ES_CONTINUOUS|ES_SYSTEM_REQUIRED)`, then `ES_SYSTEM_REQUIRED` will be set in the `SystemExecutionState`. In my own testing, none of the other per-thread execution state flags appear to impact the system execution state.